# How would I recognize a certain tone/beep/sound in Client-Side JS? (using Web Audio API)

Tags: javascript, web, audio, browser

I am trying to recognize a certain audio clip heard using the microphone on a browser. This clip could be a beep/short tone of a specific preferably high frequency that is played by another device (something similar to how Google Tone works).

I am new to the Web Audio API and currently using "getByteFrequencyData()" from an AudioContext Analyzer to check for a high decibel value in a particular frequency and using that to trigger as "recognized". But as you may have guessed, this is a useless hack and doesn't work half the time.

I have the original sound byte that is being played on the other device and it is in the 10000-12000 freq. range so that other sounds in the environment do not interfere with the recognition. Is there any way to recognize such a beep on a browser in a decent amount of time?

Sound byte and sample code attached.

```js
let AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
audioContext = new AudioContext();

navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then((stream) => {
                let audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                let analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
                analyser.fftSize = 2048;
                audioStream.connect(analyser);

                x.analyser = analyser;
                x.bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
            })
      .catch(
                (error) =>
                    (userAlert.innerHTML =
                        'Please allow access to your microphone.<br />' + error)
            );
      
      let frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(x.bufferLength);
      let getFrequency = () => {
          let totalFrequency = 0;
          x.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyArray);

          for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            totalFrequency += Math.floor(frequencyArray[i + 52]);
          }

          if (totalFrequency > 500) {
            // recognized
          } else {
            // continue
          }
          getFrequency();
      }
```

[Tone Example (assume 0.2s sound byte)](https://szynalski.com/tone#10000,v0.75)